# Adding widget to homescreen

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm afraid I've never owned an android device and only have the emulator to work with.

I am building a widget (>= API 14) and would like to test it on the homescreen. However, I have no idea how to actually create my widget! A long press on the homescreen just shows the "Select wallpaper from" popup.

I can see it in the list when I use the Widget preview app but as part of my testing I want to test real functionality. How do I get the widget to appear on the homescreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get the widget to appear on the homescreen?

Open your launcher. Keep swiping right-to-left to get to the app widgets. Long-press on an app widget to add it to the home screen.

Comment: Looking at the homescreen and swiping left or right just takes me to alternate screens. Swiping left once does show a nav which deals with bluetooth, brightness etc. Swiping right shows 2 blank screens. I am using the `google-4.0-480x720-hdpi` AVD. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: @Haraldo: "swiping left or right just takes me to alternate screens" -- you missed the "open your launcher" step. In a stock Android 4.x emulator, that's the center icon of the five across the bottom of the home screen.